# Códigos de error de servidor IIS 500 0 0

Tags: iis, windows-server

Me encuentro ejecutando una aplicación de conversión de archivos de **ASP.NET** desde **php**, esta funciona sin problemas si ejecuto el sistema como usuario desde el servidor.

Sin embargo cuando los usuarios ejecutan el sistema fuera del servidor notifican que el proceso de conversión no funciona, revisando el log de errores tengo esto

> 2019-12-05 20:27:34 IPdelservidor POST /FilesConverterApi/api/converter - 8080 - IPdelservidor- - 500 0 0 xxxxx
>   Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0

Entiendo que el `error 500` es un error interno del servidor sin embargo los errores siguientes entiendo que son de error en el módulo.

¿Qué es lo que me indica este error?

¿Influye de alguna manera que el servidor esté bloqueado por sesión cuando ellos consultan al servicio?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta los errores siguientes para saber de qué se tratan.

Comment: El el único que se despliega

Answer (score 0):

Un error **500 Internal Server Error**, es un error general para cuando el servidor se encuentra con una condición inesperada que le impide cumplir con la solicitud ([Según su definición en RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.1)).

Lo más seguro es que parte del proceso esté lanzando una excepción y no está siendo controlada, en específico en esta ruta `/FilesConverterApi/api/converter`.

Una opción sería ir a los logs de la aplicación y/o en base de datos, si tuviesen alguna tabla especifica para ello. Lo ideal sería realizar la depuración del escenario que genera error para así poder detectar a detalle el porqué se genera la excepción y como controlarla adecuadamente, y/o en su defecto mejorar el reporte de error tal que este sea más especifico (informativo) y no tan génerico.